# IIS sending RST flag on "Idle Connection Timeout"

Tags: iis-8, netscaler, tcp-rst

Troubleshooting a intermittent connection issue we noticed that IIS 8.5 on "Idle connection timeout"(default 120sec) is sending a RST flag to Loadbalancer instead of FIN flag.

1. Is this is a standard behaviour of IIS to send RST flag on idle timeouts?
2. "Vendor app" -> "Load Balancer Netscalar" -> "IIS"

   The issue we are facing is when IIS sends a RST flag on idle time out to Loadbalancer, the load balancer is not communicating this to the "vendor app" which made the request.

so while the connection b/w LB and IIS is closed, the connection b/w vendor app and LB is still in established state, which seems to be causing intermittent connection issues(Target server failed to respond).

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Any product should be developed in a way to handle RST as well as FIN, as RST is quite typical (like you tested) when a connection should be terminated (timeout is a good reason to reset). So in your case, you need support from Citrix to see how to drop the connection between NetScaler and the vendor app.